# Foreach JSON and render to select - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've returning data after call ajax success and try to render the data into  which select not already defined in html. Iam rendering select when a button click then prepend to table tbody.

here's my code:

**getInventories**

```
function getInventories(store_id){
        return $.ajax({
             url: '{{ url("api/v1/inventory-item/") }}/'+store_id,
             type: "GET"
          });
      }
```

**Button**

```
$('#add_manually').click(function(){
      var store_id = $('#store_id').val();
      var data = getInventories(store_id);
      var $select = $('#select_invetory');
      var html = '<tr>';
          html += '<td></td>';
          html += `<td>
                      <select id="select_inventory" class="form-control"></select>
                            </td>`;
         html += '<td>'+ $('#select_toko option:selected').text() +'</td>';
         html += '<td></td>';
         html += '<td><input type="text" name="actual_stock" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Stock Opname"/></td>';
         html += '<td></td>';
         html += '<td></td>';
         html += '<td></td>';
         html += '</tr>';
         $('#table-stock-opname tbody').prepend(html);
         data.success(function(data){
              data.forEach(element => {
                   $select.append('<option value="'+element.id+'"> '+element.name+'</option>');
               });
            })
        });
```

I got nothing error in my code and the data response show but doesnt append to the select option. any idea ?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$('#select_invetory')` and `id="select_inventory"` do not match, so your jQuery selector won't find an element. Typo.

Comment: @Ele i've edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you do now, where this line executes, `var $select = $('#select_inventory');`, won't work since the `#select_inventory` element hasn't been added to the DOM at that point.

Your for-each loop will need this

```
data.forEach(element => {
    $('#select_inventory').append('<option value="'+element.id+'"> '+element.name+'</option>');
});
```

or you have to move the statement `var $select = $('#select_inventory');` after the table been added to the DOM.

*And there were a typo as well, a missing `n` in `#select_invetory`*

---

Another possible solution could be to simply insert the `option` straight into the `select`, like this

```
$('#add_manually').click(function(){
    var store_id = $('#store_id').val();
    var data = getInventories(store_id);
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td></td>';
    html += '<td><select id="select_inventory" class="form-control">';

    data.forEach(element => {
        html += '<option value="' + element.id + '"> ' + element.name + '</option>';
    });

    html += '</select></td>';
    html += '<td>'+ $('#select_toko option:selected').text() +'</td>';
    html += '<td></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="actual_stock" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Stock Opname"/></td>';
    html += '<td></td>';
    html += '<td></td>';
    html += '<td></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#table-stock-opname tbody').prepend(html);
});
```

Comment: @Aslam Added a 2nd option as well, and hopefully that will also give me an upvote :)